# How to implement ldap authentication(without admin credentials) in django

Tags: django, ldap, django-authentication, django-auth-ldap

My setup: Django-3.0, Python-3.8, django_auth_ldap 
I have LDAP Server (Active Directory Server) in my organization.
I am building a Django Application which serves some operations for all the users.
I know Django has built-in User Authentication mechanism, But it authenticates if users are present in User Model Database.

**But my requirement is.** 
All user entries are in LDAP Server(Active Directory). Using proper user credentials LDAP server authenticates me. 
I Created a Login Page in Django **'accounts'** app, 
1. whenever I enter username and password from Login Page, it should Authenticate using My Organization LDAP Server.
2. After Login I have to hold the session for the logged in user for 5 active minutes. (Django auth session)

I saw **django_auth_ldap** package gives some insight for my purpose.
I have these contents in **settings.py**.

```
import ldap

##Ldap settings
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://myldapserver.com"
AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {ldap.OPT_REFERRALS : 0}
AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = "uid=%(user)s, OU=USERS,dc=myldapserver, dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_START_TLS = True

#Register authentication backend
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
            "django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend",

            ]
```

Calling authenticate in **views.py**.

```
from django_auth_ldap.backend import LDAPBackend
def accounts_login(request):
    username = ""
    password = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        auth = LDAPBackend()
        user = auth.authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect("/")
        else:
            error = "Authentication Failed"
            return render(request, "accounts/login.html", 'error':error)

    return render(request, "accounts/login.html")
```

But using above method always authenticate fails with the LDAP Server.

If I call using normal python simple_bind_s(), authentication is working fine to same LDAP server.

```
import ldap
def ldap_auth(username, password):
    conn = ldap.initialize(myproj.settings.LDAP_AUTH_URI)
    try:
        ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
        #ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)
        conn.simple_bind_s(username, password)
    except ldap.LDAPError as e:
        return f'failed to authenticate'

    conn.unbind_s()
    return "Success"
```

Can anybody suggest me to make LDAPBackend Authentication work as per my requirement ?

Note: I do not have admin permission of LDAP Server.

Answer (score 9):

This is how I would do it with *ldap3* and without *django_auth_ldap* packages.

1 - Create a custom AuthenticationBackend in `your_app/backends.py` :

```py
import logging

from ldap3 import Server, Connection
from ldap3.core.exceptions import LDAPBindError

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model



logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
UserModel = get_user_model()


class LDAPBackend:

    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        # set username to lowercase for consistency
        username = username.lower()
        # get the bind client to resolve DN
        logger.info('authenticating %s' % username)
        # set your server
        server = Server(settings.LDAP_HOST, get_info=ALL)
        try:
            conn = Connection(server, f"{username}@{settings.LDAP_DOMAIN}", password=password, auto_bind=True)
        except LDAPBindError as e:
            logger.info('LDAP authentication failed')
            logger.info(e)
            return None
        user = UserModel.objects.update_or_create(username=username)
        return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return UserModel._default_manager.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

2 - Declare `LDAPBackend` as your authentication backend in `settings.py`

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'your_app.backends.LDAPBackend', 
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
]
```

This allows you to use django's native function for authentication, and it work with the admin.

To have session only work for 5 minutes, add this setting to your `settings.py` file :

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 5 * 60
```

Let me know if it works for your.

Comment: Does this require any special privileges on the server side?

Comment: Honestly I don’t know but you can easily test it on your python shell.

Comment: Got some problems using ur code:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66648793/implement-authentication-in-request-send-to-ldap-server-for-connecting-in-python